# XSLT getting some unwanted value

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE UploadXML SYSTEM "ex_v222.dtd">
    <UploadXML><Version>1.1</Version>
<Properties>
<Property>
<IntegratorID>3232321</IntegratorID>
<IntegratorPropertyID>12312312-3</IntegratorPropertyID>
<IntegratorOfficeID>1231231231</IntegratorOfficeID>....
```

for some reason,the following XSL file, always gets the 1.1 value and place it before the envelope element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:param name="Z">2312</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="A">KKK</xsl:param>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

        <xsl:template match='/UploadXML/Properties'> 
        <Envelope>
        <Body>
        <add_adverts>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='Property'/>
        </add_adverts>
        </Body>
        </Envelope>
        </xsl:template>
```

.... (I believe the template implementation is not important..)

What I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
1.1<Envelope xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <Body>
    <add_adverts>
      <advert>
```

.
.
.

See that 1.1 there? why?
any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing that because that is the default behavior of XSLT for a node that doesn't match any templates.  To specifically not copy the Version element content you can just use an empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="Version"/>
```

Comment: Great! Solved the problem. Answer will be accepted in 3 minutes (something with stackoverflow..)

Answer (score 2):

**You need to read about the XSLT processing model** and understand how **[XSLT built-in (default) templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule)** are used.

The observed behavior is due to the XSLT built-in template for a text node, which simply copies it:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

**The solution is to override this template for any text nodes that should not appear in the output** with a template that has empty body (does nothing and thus doesn't copy the text node). In this case:

```
<xsl:template match="Version/text()"/>
```